# Why AdMob reload with every mouse click? -- Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout, admob

After a long time trying to figure out how to implement AdMob into my Flutter project I finally made it to work, well almost. it appears that AdMob gets reloaded every time after a mouse click or a tap for that matter. since my project is already long and complicated, I have also tested AdMob with a simple project to see if I get the same problem. I choose to test it on the sample push-button counter that comes with every new project. I slightly modify it so it would resemble somehow my original project. Sure enough, the AdMob reload on mouse clicks happens there too. So, how to prevent this from happening? obviously, Goole won't see this in a bright eye and they might suspend AdMob account for problems like this.

here is what happens:

[image]

Here is my Main.Dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'admob_service.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(
        title: 'Hello',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.blue,
                    onPrimary: Colors.white,
                    shadowColor: Colors.black,
                    elevation: 10,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                    minimumSize: const Size(300, 65), //////// HERE
                  ),
                  child: const Text('Click Here', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
                  onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 50,
                      child: AdWidget(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        ad: AdMobService.createBannerAd()..load(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the admob_service.dart supplement file which contain the adMob info

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class AdMobService {
  static String get bannerAdUnitId => Platform.isAndroid ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111' : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716';

  static initialize() {
    MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  }

  static BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    BannerAd ad = BannerAd(
        adUnitId: bannerAdUnitId,
        size: AdSize.banner,
        request: const AdRequest(),
        listener: AdManagerBannerAdListener(
          onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
            ad.dispose();
          },
        ));
    return ad;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the.   `key: UniqueKey(),`  from the code solved the problem.

A UniqueKey class is a key that is only equal to itself.

This cannot be created with a const constructor because that implies that all instantiated keys would be the same instance and therefore not be unique.

```
Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 300,
                          height: 50,
                          child: AdWidget(
                            // key: UniqueKey(), 
                            ad: AdMobService.createBannerAd()..load(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Here's how it works now:

[image]